# Android IME suggestions view overlaps application

Tags: android, view, keyboard, ime

In my software keyboard the candidates view overlaps user application and hides the bottom part of the UI.

[image: Android IME Screenshot]

This happens in Android 6.0 and higher. The same APK works fine in Android 4.4. The onMeasure() handlers for keyboard view and candidates view are implemented in the following way:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int rwidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int w = Math.min(InputViewMetrics.screenWidth, rwidth);
    int h = InputViewMetrics.candidatesViewHeight;
    this.setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
}
```

I also call setCandidatesViewShown() with true or false depending on the input mode, but toggling the candidates view does not fix the overlap. Again, this behavior is not occurring in previous versions of Android. The app is compiled for compatibility with the following lines in the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
```

What can be done to fix this overlap? How do I ensure that the user app refreshes its layout when the candidates view visibility changes?

Comment: is it related to adjustpan, adjustsize kind of thing

Comment: @ManojPerumarath The app resizes its UI, but ignores the additional candidates view. Seems like candidates view is abandoned in higher versions of android when calculating size adjustment. But I need to prevent this from the IME, not from user application, which I have no control of.

Comment: The current focus is on the blue view, which also is an input view, so android ignore all the view below it. That's the reason

Comment: @ManojPerumarath In Android 4.4 the top view is adjusted correctly when the candidates view is toggled. In Android 6.0 the top view only adjusts to keyboard height, but not the candidates view height.

Comment: what about the screen size and screen density, @bkxp

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late but may be helpful for someone else. I fixed it overriding the onComputeInsets:

```
override fun onComputeInsets(outInsets: Insets?) {
    super.onComputeInsets(outInsets)
    if (!isFullscreenMode) {
        outInsets?.contentTopInsets = outInsets?.visibleTopInsets
    }
}
```